# How to parse Zimbra data to CSV

Tags: csv, awk

I'm not experienced in awk language but I need to convert some data (Zimbra distribution list and its members) to CSV format.
My data looks like below:

```
# distributionList zimbradladmins@example.com memberCount=0
zimbraMailAlias: zimbradladmins@example.com

# distributionList monitoring@example.com memberCount=3
zimbraMailAlias: monitoring@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Eatable@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Boorish@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Flawless@example.com

# distributionList all@example.com memberCount=10
zimbraMailAlias: all@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Legal@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Joyous@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: helpdesk@special.example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Crazy@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Successful@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: operator@special.example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: pawelm@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: tomaszb@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: wojciech@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: wojtekb@example.com
```

What I want to achieve in output:

```
distributionList,member
zimbradladmins@example.com,
monitoring@example.com,Eatable@example.com
monitoring@example.com,Boorish@example.com
monitoring@example.com,Flawless@example.com
all@example.com,Legal@example.com
and so on...
```

As you can see there is DL with no any members (zimbradladmins@example.com). If so, there should be no value in CSV file.
I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: I assume it's not *required* to use awk specifically - any tool that is installed on your machine will be fine, correct?

Comment: Yes. It can be e.g. python but v2. It's mail server (Debian) and I don't want to install additional tools that's not included in default :)

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk, and relying on the comment line above the wanted emails:

```
awk -F':? ' '
   BEGIN{print "distributionList,member"}         # print header
   /memberCount=0/{print $3,""}                   # print mail alias without user email
   /^# distributionList /{a=$3}                   # store mail alias
   $1=="zimbraMailForwardingAddress"{print a,$2}  # print mail alias and user email
' OFS=, file
```

Note that the script also print the line `zimbradladmins@example.com,`